# What is a continuous array?

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv

In the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat), there is a mention of continuous array.

> "It makes sense to check whether all the input/output arrays are continuous, namely, have no gaps at the end of each row."

What does it mean by having no gaps at the end of each row. Can someone explain with an example please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An OpenCV array is continuous when all the memory allocated to it is organized sequentially. In other words, there is no variable surrounded by such array: the array (image, matrix, etc) can be treated as an one "single row" vector.

There is a method called `isContinuous` in the `cv::Mat` to check if one is continuous. From the documentation, the quote that explains it:

> The method is used in quite a few of OpenCV functions. The point is that element-wise operations (such as arithmetic and logical operations, math functions, alpha blending, color space transformations, and others) do not depend on the image geometry. Thus, if all the input and output arrays are continuous, the functions can process them as very long single-row vectors.

Look for a complete explanantion (with examples) in the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#bool%20Mat::isContinuous()%20const).

Comment: Your answer clarifies everything in simple words. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

A better word would be "contiguous" in my opinion.

Bitmaps have a concept of "stride." The "stride" makes the bitmap/pixmap conform to a particular alignment restriction of underlying hardware or software. A "stride" (also called "pitch") is the distance between the first byte of one scanline, and the first byte of the next scanline. The total size of the bitmap/pixmap array is pitch times number of rows.

The pitch doesn't have to be the same as "sizeof(pixel) * width" for several reasons.

The first reason is when data has to be aligned. For example, when a pixel is 3 bytes, and scanlines have to be 4-byte aligned, then a 3-pixel-wide bitmap would contain 9 bytes of pixel data per scanline, but the alignment would round up to the nearest higher multiple of 4, which makes it 12 bytes pitch. The "extra" data at the end is what would make each scanline not "continuous" in the description you post.

Another reason is when you have a bigger bitmap, say a 1024x1024 picture, and you extract a sub-picture from that, say a 128x64 region. Rather than copying the data, you can share the data with the original bitmap, and then set the "width" to 128 pixels, "height" to 64 pixels, set the "data" pointer to point at the first pixel of the sub-region, and set the stride/pitch to be that of the 1024 pixel bitmap -- that way, you can point at more than one region of different sizes within the same bitmap data.

Comment: I believe contiguous is a better term too. "continuous" makes a huge confusion with continuity of mathematical functions, very used in signal processing (strongly related with the purpose of OpenCV).

Comment: Thanks Jon for the detailed clarification. @MatheusGadelha, yeah I am from signal processing background that's why I was also confused.